# Whats the limit for the number of fields in GETPIVOTDATA

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Whats the limit on the number fields, items that can be used in formula `GETPIVOTDATA`. IN the help it says multiple items can be referenced, and it works for 2 - 1 row and 1 column.

But when i tried to reference 1 row and 2 columns it is not working.

```
GETPIVOTDATA("2016 ($)",'Pivot2'!$A$2,"Product",A43,"2016 Status","Yes","SPA","Revenue")
```

is not working and giving either 0 or #REF as the result but when i stop at

```
GETPIVOTDATA("2016 ($)",'Pivot2'!$A$2,"Product",A43,"2016 Status","Yes")
```

Then its working. Is 2 the limit or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: are all these fields exposed in the pivot table in current view? I just made a formula with `3` arguments: `=GETPIVOTDATA("EDW Revenue (Net Amt USD)",$A$3,"B - Account Number","A-01232249","B - Account Name","Bank of Nova Scotia","B2CC MC","000000008005016211")` If you manually map the reference you want in a cell (by typing = then select the pivot cell), you will see where you error is.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: Its working now. I did as you suggested, but cant figure what's wrong with the formula above. Thanks a lot.